# Using pipes to communicate interactively doesn't work. I tried flush() too. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pipe, popen

There is a parent and a child, they are connected via pipes. The parent does a non blocking read from the child and also does a blocking write on the child's pipe. Additionally I use select() with timeout for the non blocking read.

the code for the parent:

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
import signal
import fcntl
from select import select
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['python', 'bot2.py'],stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, close_fds=True)

flg = fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, flg | os.O_NONBLOCK)

for i in range(5):
    p.stdin.write('hello world {}\n'.format(i))
    p.stdin.flush()
    # sleep(2.0)
    ready = select([p.stdout.fileno()], [], [], 5.0)
    if len(ready) == 1:
        print 'msg from bot: {}'.format(os.read(p.stdout.fileno(), 100))
    else:
        print "The bot did not print anything"
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

code for the child (bot2.py)

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
from select import select

sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
while True:
    a = raw_input()
    print a
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

The goal is to establish a connections between the processes so they can read and write to pipes alternatively. I think flush() is not doing the job. I tried to use `python -u` to set buffer size to zero. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select()` returns a triple of list of objects that are ready. So, In your case `len(ready)` always returns 3. It should instead be `len(ready[0])` if you are trying to read from the child.